# Azure Stream Analytics Job query: how to case bigint to float?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

My input is JSON like this:

```json
{
        "ClientStateOrProvince": "Noord-Holland",
        "ClientType": "PC",
        "IKey": "6ca435d6-f333-4888-9288-8e3170a12664",
        "ItemCount": 1,
        "Max": 2,
        "Min": 2,
}
```

The properties `Min` and `Max` are integers in the example above but they could also be decimal numbers. If I test out my query in the portal's editor, both `Min` and `Max` are showing up as `bigint` in the "Test results" pane although I applied a `CAST(Min AS float) AS Min`:

```sql
SELECT
    [...]
    CAST(Min AS float) AS Min,
    Max
FROM
    Input
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I enforce a `float` data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the UI only. The UI will deduct the data type based on the value, no matter what the `CAST()` specifies.
The moment an output is added (for example ADL2 Parquet), the resulting data type will match the result of the case, in my case `float`.